# Why is JavaScript parsing non-datetime strings into Date objects?

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I have come across a JavaScript quirk, and I am hoping for an explanation of the behavior.

JavaScript is allowing strings like `'Foo 100'` to be parsed into a valid Date Object.

For example, the following code:

```
const date = new Date('Foo 100');
console.log(date.toString());
```

will result in the following output:

```
Fri Jan 01  100 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (WET)
```

I do notice that the output looks funny (there are two spaces before the number 100 which only seems to appear when you give the Date constructor weird values), but as far as JavaScript is concerned this is a totally valid Date object.

**Can someone explain the JavaScript quirk that is allowing this to happen?** I am specifically trying to test for this behavior so that I can prevent it (or write a validation for datetime strings).

Thanks!

---

**Update 01:**

According to [Mozilla's JavaScript Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> **dateString**: String value representing a date. The string should be in
>   a format recognized by the Date.parse() method (IETF-compliant RFC
>   2822 timestamps and also a version of ISO8601).

it basically says that the `dateString` should represent a date, but even when looking over the RFC 2822 and ISO8601 datetime string specifications listed above, I can't see a format that would suggest the the pattern of `'Foo 100'` was cleverly disguised as a valid date value.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Thanks @nurdyguy, but it's not helpful to read through the documentation. The documentation simply says that a `dateString` should be a "String value representing a date." --- which is why I have to ask "why is JavaScript accepting 'Foo 100' to represent a date?"

Comment: moment.js will help you.

Comment: *However, invalid values in date strings not recognized as ISO format as defined by ECMA-262 may or may not result in NaN, depending on the browser and values provided* and *It is not recommended to use Date.parse as until ES5, parsing of strings was entirely implementation dependent. There are still many differences in how different hosts parse date strings, therefore date strings should be manually parsed*

Comment: That's the way it is. Alot of JS builtins accept 'wrong' values and give you something usable back (of the correct return type). In my personal preference, this is a workable solution. If I see that the output is wrong, I know I constructed the date wrong. If the browser would just give an error and stop the script, you need to at least open the devtools for a stacktrace.

Comment: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-date.prototype.tostring

Comment: @radiovisual That's because you didn't read far enough.  For one thing, "Note: parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local."

Comment: For validation purposes you could always check `getTime()` on the returned date.  I get `-59011437600000` and presuming you want something after 1969 this is probably not what you want.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions everyone. I am more or less looking for an explanation of the quirky behavior, everywhere I go I can only find justifications that "JavaScript is quirky, just deal with it", and while I totally accept JS for all it's quirks, I was just hoping to get a more "behind the scenes" explanation as to why this particular quirk is manifesting. Again, thanks for all your suggestions. I am reading through the links you sent right now.

Comment: Please see [*Date.parse(new Date(…)) NaN in Safari*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23440515/date-parsenew-date-nan-in-safari). Parsing of strings by the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent for parsing) is **almost entirely implementation dependent**. Why? Because [*it's specified that way*](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.parse), so just don't do it. Use a function (2 or 3 lines of code) or a library like [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha) or [*moment.js*](https://momentjs.com/).

Comment: Also, `new Date()` always returns a Date, if it can't parse the string it will return an invalid date (i.e. Date instance with time value set to NaN).